# Bluetooth won't turn on on Lenovo G510 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, lenovo

It was working just yesterday and now I see the greyed out icon on the bar and enabling Bluetooth does nothing. I checked `rfkill` and it's not blocked.

`dmesg | grep Blue` produces this:

```
[    5.045301] usb 3-7: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   16.443866] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.19
[   16.443882] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.443889] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.443891] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.443899] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.998446] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   22.998457] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   22.998460] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   23.362132] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   23.362134] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   23.362141] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   26.368809] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c6d tx timeout
[   61.849157] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   61.849165] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
```

`hciconfig hci0 up` just times out.

Any ideas?

Edit: Added the results of lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep -i firmware; dmesg | grep -e Atheros -e Broadcom; uname -a; hciconfig -a

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174f:147b Syntek 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3218]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3801]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
[    0.149648] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[23593.016925] usb 3-7: device firmware changed
[23602.228576] usb 3-7: device firmware changed
[    4.110564] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [20:1a:06:30:58:a5]
[    5.333718] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[   16.208246] ieee80211 phy0: Atheros AR9485 Rev:1 mem=0xffffc90011e00000, irq=17
[23593.330774] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[23594.284747] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [20:1a:06:30:58:a5]
[23599.693537] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[23602.550237] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
[23603.690690] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Qualcomm Atheros AR816x/AR817x Ethernet [20:1a:06:30:58:a5]
[23608.060295] usb 3-7: Manufacturer: Atheros Communications
Linux bill-Lenovo-G510 3.16.0-33-generic #44~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 13 10:33:29 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: A4:DB:30:05:66:1F  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 183:5
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:28722 acl:1869 sco:0 events:163 errors:0
    TX bytes:1435 acl:29 sco:0 commands:57 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0xd8 0x7f 0x7b 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'bill-Lenovo-G510'
    Class: 0x6c0100
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Audio, Telephony
    Device Class: Computer, Uncategorized
    HCI Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Revision: 0x102
    LMP Version: 4.0 (0x6)  Subversion: 0x1
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

Comment: Add the results from `lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; dmesg | grep -i firmware; dmesg | grep -e Atheros -e Broadcom; uname -a; hciconfig -a` to the question

Comment: Strange that `hciconfig -a` shows that it is working.  Does `lsmod | grep bluetooth` show ath3k?

Comment: Well, the really weird thing is that I figured out today that on first boot it doesn't work but if I suspend and wake, it works fine...

`lsmod | grep bluetooth` shows

`bluetooth             446409  28 bnep,hidp,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm`

Comment: Very strange as my g710 with the same combo has worked fine since kernel 3.16.0-32 before that I needed a workaround to get it to work at boot because of a firmware loading issue

Answer (score 1):

This might need my old work around

```
echo "blacklist ath3k" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath3k.conf
```

Then edit rc.local `sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local`

And add a couple lines so the last 3 lines are

```
sleep 45
modprobe ath3k
exit 0
```

Save, exit and reboot